# how to evaluate prior year(last year same month) in SQL with gap in between data(not continuous) and convert SumIF statements from Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, excel-formula

I have a raw dataset in excel like this
[image]

I'm trying to change some of the derived fields from Excel to SQL. I'm new to SQL and not aware of the syntaxes

[image]

as an example, column PY = (sum of column M*W where column B(2022-1 in this case), column C(site A in this case), column D(Flavor in this case) and column E(Americas in this case)/ sum of weight column where column B(2022-1 in this case), column C(site A in this case), column D(Flavor in this case) and column E(Americas in this case))

Please help me in the Prior year formula and can guide me in the right direction. basically it is making the calculations for the prior year same month.

Comment: I think you might want to look into [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in SQL Server, if I'm understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ZLK LAG() function is giving me prior month instead of prior year same month